# ubuntu 20.04.2 pi-hole install cmd not working

Tags: command-line, ssl, curl

Several questions on here from people as dense as I, but I haven't seen my problem.

Just installed.

Runs all updates.

open cmd and enter `sudo curl -sSL https://install.pi-hole.net I bash`

sudo: curl: command not found

`sudo apt install curl -sSL...`

E: Command line option 'S' not understood

remove

E: Command line option 'L'

Hopefully you can tell I read a cool article and got in over my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First mistake is you put an `I` before `bash` rather than a `|` (vertical bar). Second mistake is you did the install command wrong. It's `sudo apt install curl` without any command line options after.

So it's the following for pi-hole install:

```
sudo apt install curl
curl -sSL https://install.pi-hole.net | sudo bash
```

Comment: Thanks. All better now. Will be better for the next time.

Answer (score 1):

I want to explain what @Aenfa is saying a bit more. Just so that you understand it (fixing a problem is good, but understanding what you did wrong is better).

---

We'll start with the installation of curl:

You did the following: `sudo apt install curl -sSL...`

What you need to do is: `sudo apt install curl`

Why? Because the `-sSL` are options for curl. So when using the `curl` command, you choose to enable/use some of the options that it has (that being: `-s` for silent, `-L` for no progress bar and `-S`  to still show errors eventhough `-s` is used). Those are called flags and are used all the time. You can see the flags available (and general usage) for a command doing `man [[command]]`. So in this case `man curl`.

When installing something (in this case `curl`), you just choose what you want to install by giving the name. So `sudo apt install curl` for example. Or `sudo apt install wget`. Or `sudo apt install nano`. You get it. The `-sSL` is part of the curl command, and when installing curl, you're not using curl so those flags don't apply. You were using `apt`. And `apt` doesn't support the flag -s, -S and -L, so it was giving errors!

---

Now the `I` part:

This one's a bit harder, so I suggest that you look it up. Search for `linux piping explained`. Because it is called piping. You misunderstood the `|` for the `I`. When piping, you use the `|` (shift and then the key above enter on your keyboard).

So that was the problem. You were trying to pipe, but used `I` instead of `|`. It's okay. We all make mistakes!

But what is piping?

`[[command 1]] | [[command 2]] | [[command 3]]`

I again suggest searching it up but in short, the output of one command will be the input for the second command, and the output of the second command will be the input for the third command.

Example:

```
cas@Waveserver:~$ echo "this is a test"
this is a test
cas@Waveserver:~$ echo "this is a test" | sed "s/test/joke/"
this is a joke
cas@Waveserver:~$ echo "this is a test" | sed "s/test/joke/" | grep -o "joke"
joke
```

The output of the echo command is simple ofcourse. It's just the text that is echo'd.

Now we are going to pipe that output to sed and replace `test` with `joke`. So the output of echo becomes the input of sed. So it is able to replace the word, because in it's input, the word `test` is present.

Now THAT output is going to be piped to the grep command. This means that `this is a joke` will be the input for grep (notice that I'm using a, that's right, flag! When we do `man grep` and scroll down, we see that `-o` means `--only-matching` or "Print only the matching part of the line instead of marking the matched text red"). So grep searches in it's input for `joke`, which it finds and that will be it's output!

So three commands were executed, but there's only one output, because the output of the 1st and 2nd command were (instead of outputting to the terminal) redirected to the input of the following command in the pipe.

In your case, you were curl-ing a script (used for installing pi-hole) and piping that to the command `bash`, which basically means: "run the script". So:

`[[ get the script ]] | [[ run it ]]`

You can pipe as many or as little commands as you want. In a few scripts that I've written, I  have 8 commands all piped after eachother, and other times I just have 1 or 2 commands piped!

---

I hope you understand it now!

EDIT: Here's one of those long pipes that I found somewhere inside my scripts!

`curl -s -L https://plex.tv/pms/downloads/5.json | jq -M | grep -PA 3 "Ubuntu.*?64-bit" | tail -n 1 | grep -Po "\"\Khttp.*?(?=\")"`

`[[curl a webpage containing info about updates for plex media server]] | [[ pretty-print the json output ]] | [[ grab the string and three lines below (-..A 3) that string ]] | [[ from that output, only show the bottom line ]] | [[ grab the url that's inside the line ]]`

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful. I'm realizing I should look into all the commands I'm inputing so I get a better understanding of what exactly I'm doing. I knew about the | vs I but couldn't figure out how to do it, but knowing why it is used is extreamly helpful. Thanks agian.